# Execute Oracle Function from SSIS OLE DB Command

Tags: sql, oracle, ssis, sqlcommand, oledbcommand

I am trying to call a function from oracle using OLE DB Command for SSIS, I have the connection set up Correctly but I think my Syntax for calling the function is incorrect?

```
EXEC UPDATE_PERSON ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? output
```

I have used this on a SQL stored proc for testing & it has worked. the oracal connection is 3rd party & they have just supplied the function name & expected parameters. I should get 1 return parameter.

The Error:

```
Error at Data Flow Task [OLE DB Command [3013]]: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR. AN OLE DB error has occurred. Error code 0x80040e14.
An OLE DB record is available. Source: "Microsoft OLE DB Provider for Oracle" Hresult: 0x80040E14
Description: "ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement".
```

Comment: Are you calling a function or a stored procedure?

Comment: Im calling a function in oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your syntax you have to change the command " EXCU " to " EXEC ".

**EXEC** UPDATE_PERSON ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? OUTPUT
i have to mention that there is no need for  { }

other than that you have to be aware of your full path of the SP that your are executing " by means of specifying [databaseName].[dbo]. if needed

Regards,
S.ANDOURA

Comment: My bad that was a typo I was using EXEC. im not using a SP, im using oracle function?

Comment: Well, as far OLE DB Command are designed to execut sql commands or stored procedures wrapping a set of sql query, so have you thought of changing the way of calling your method and instead use an SP ?
I can understand that SP are lower in performance in terms of retriving set of rows from your db "Try calling it using a SELECT Statement". but if you want to use the OLE DB command in your package you have to check on the later propsed solution.

Regards,
S.ANDOURA

Comment: Thanks Ando, I cant change to a SP as im connecting to a 3rd party using their function that's in place. but thanks. I think im nearly there with it, just have a couple wrong data type parameter issues now to work through.

Comment: Great news! gdluck Richard!

Answer (score 1):

Try wrapping it in curly braces:

```
{EXEC UPDATE_PERSON ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? output}
```

I don't think Oracle functions have output parameters - are you absolutely certain this is a function and not a proc? functions don't normally perform updates either.

Comment: Thanks I got to work looking like this: SELECT crm_customer.UPDATE_PERSON( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) FROM dual

Answer (score 0):

syntax:

```
SELECT crm_customer.UPDATE_PERSON( ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?) FROM dual
```

I will update further details once solution has been completed

Thanks for the help