# Passing variable to PostgreSQL function from SSIS OLE DB Command

Tags: postgresql, ssis, oledbcommand

I am trying to call a PostgreSQL function and pass value to it using OLE DB Command in SSIS.

My PostgreSQL function signature is as follows:

```
UpdateZone(ZoneId integer,ZoneName varchar(50)) returns void
```

It works with static values like

```
Exec UpdateZone(1,'South')
```

But not able to parametrise it like

```
Exec UpdateZone ?,?
```

[image]

[image]

I am using PGNP OLEDB Providers for PostgreSQL.

[Execute Oracle Function from SSIS OLE DB Command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21330402/execute-oracle-function-from-ssis-ole-db-command)
 Explains the working with Oracle.

Answer (score 0):

Giving the SQLCommand as shown below solved the problem.

```
select UpdateZone (cast(? as int),?)
```

Seems like it is not able to recognize a parameter type when it is not varchar. So had to explicitly cast the place holder to the intended type used in the function.

Please suggest any better ways of doing it if any.